# how to mitigate possible failures of js string-similarity

Tags: node.js, similarity

i am trying to get the manufacturer of a product based on their name and for that i am using [`string-similarity`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-similarity) package for nodeJs by comparing the name to an existing list of manufactureres that i have. the problem i got is that sometimes it deviates completely from an obvious best match.

i am running this on [runkit](https://npm.runkit.com/string-similarity) :

```
var stringSimilarity = require("string-similarity")

var matches = stringSimilarity.findBestMatch("BLENDER MOULINETTE MOULINEX AR6801EG - 200G - 800W AVEC - BOL 1.5L -  BLANC - GARANTIE 1 AN"
.toLowerCase()
.replace(/\-/g, '')
.replace(/[0-9]./g,'')
.replace(/\s/g,''), [
  "intel",
  "moulinex",
  "cuiseurs",
  "under armour"
]);
```

and these are the results

- 0: {target: "intel", rating: 0.1111111111111111}
- 1: {target: "moulinex", rating: 0.24561403508771928}
- 2: {target: "cuiseurs", rating: 0}
- 3: {target: "under armour", rating: 0.26666666666666666}

the issue here is that "under armour" is the most rated match while "moulinex" which is literally in the name is less favorable. I tried to clean up the input string by removing numbers and spaces but it didn't change the outcome, just better ratings.